# Hey! Wake Up! Look At This Grid Puzzle!

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

The grid is divided into rooms, though some are wibbly-wobbly weird-shaped. Hey, aren't these normally supposed to be blocks? **What should the title of this puzzle really be?**

```
B S G N I L H I A I
O L F F M T R F A R
I O R R C J N E S L
A T B B I Q C N A T
X A R O N O V I F L
O W F B U N Y H J S
W R S S J U I M X E
I O N T R K A W P R
V Q F P O D L T R U
E F B Z F I Z C N T
```

[image: small grid; full size at i.stack.imgur.com/OjA4d.png]

*Special thanks to @Deusovi for testsolving this!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Wacky Waving

Step 1:

> Solve the grid as a Heyawake.
>
>  [image]
>  Overlaying this with the letter grid reveals:
>
>  [image]
>  shift first in row by sum in rpplffct

Step 2:

> Solving the grid again, this time as a Ripple effect.
>
>  [image]
>  Then shifting the first row by the sum of all numbers in that row reveals:
>
>  Z to Z course

Step 3:

> Plotting a course from Z to Z gives:
>
>  [image]
>  BFQORSSJUNOBRCJ[NQ]CVI[HF]JXERURTWAKDI

Step 4:

> Shifting the letters by the numbers of the ripple effect solution yields:
>
>  first two words for family guy tubemen

Comment: Correct, and well done!